# Can I run interval timers in AwesomeWM?

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

I am using Awesome 4.3 on Manjaro Linux (Arch) I changed from a KDE desktop to an XFCE desktop. I wrote a wallpaper switcher that will change the wallpaper randomly on four separate screens. I wrote the randomize routine in a standard Lua file for development purposes. I added it to rc.lua, but it doesn't seem that the Lua timers (luv) are running in rc.lua. I checked all the methods separately to load the wallpaper from my randomize routines, and they work perfectly when I call directly for one set of files for the four screens. As soon as I add the interval timers, nothing happens, no error, nothing at all.

This is the code simplified to load only one screen, am I missing something, taking out the awesome objects and replacing with print statements and it works perfectly in a standard Lua file

thanks any help is appreciated

```
local lfs = require('lfs') -- lua file system
local uv = require('luv') -- lua timer
local dir = "/home/jerry/Documents/wallpaper"
local images = {} -- images collection
local idx = 0
math.randomseed(os.time())

local function tablelength(T)
    local count = 0
    for _ in pairs(T) do count = count + 1 end
    return count
end

local function readImages(path)
    for file in lfs.dir(path) do
        if file ~= "." and file ~= ".." then
            images[idx] = path .. '/' .. file
            idx = idx + 1
        end
    end
end

readImages(dir);
imageCount = tablelength(images)

local function getImage()
    number = math.random(1, imageCount)
    return images[number]
end

local function setInterval(interval, callback)
    local timer = uv.new_timer()
    uv.timer_start(timer, 0, interval, callback)
    return timer
end

local function cb()
    local path = getImage()
    gears.wallpaper.maximized(path, screen[1], true)
end


timer1 = setInterval(1000, cb)
```

```
 local function cb(gears, getImage, screen, screenIndex)
    return function()
        print(gears)
        print(getImage())
        print(screen)
        print("Screen " .. screenIndex)
        return gears.wallpaper.maximized(getImage(), screen[screenIndex], true)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to call `uv.run()`. That call runs the timers.
However, it would also does not run anything else, so AwesomeWM would stop working.

`uv.run()` runs a main loop. This loop waits for events (like: A timer expires) and then handles that event. AwesomeWM also uses a main loop. It runs GLib's `GMainLoop`.

Since you cannot run two main loops at the same time, you'll have to use GLib's and AwesomeWMs facilities.
I found some docs for luv's `timer_start`: https://github.com/luvit/luv/blob/master/docs.md#uvtimer_starttimer-timeout-repeat-callback
According to this, your `timer_start(timer, 0, interval, callback)` means that the timer triggers immediately and then every second. The AwesomeWM version of this is:

```
local gears = require("gears") -- This is part of AwesomeWM
local timer1 = gears.start_new(1, function()
    print("I run once per second")
    return true -- Signal that the timer should continue running
end)
timer1:emit_signal("timeout") -- Cause the callback function to run right now
```

`gears.timer` uses GLib to run the timer: https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/blob/87e7b84ff54c050f86541421ec0aa93e325dd49d/lib/gears/timer.lua#L94

Comment: Hi and thanks, yes I left the uv.run() out of the code by accident, and yes it locks up when I use it. This is why I was reaching out. I will take a look at the gears option, the other problem I ran into was that because it is asynchronous I lose the local state and have to make sure I pass all state to the method before execution. Thanks for the heads up on gears, I will give it a try and let you know

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "lose all local states"? Lua closures should still continue the same was that they did before. For example, `local i = 1; gears.timer.start_new(1, function() print(i) ; i = i + 1 ; return true ; end)` should count up.

Comment: I was referring to within the call back, I should have been more precise. The timer is an asynchronous process and loses all closure state within the callback I got around that by currying in the state it needed.

Comment: But my example from my last comment is also asynchronous and it does not lose state (it keeps the value of `i` between invocations), so it does not lose all closure state. That's exactly what a closure is in Lua. I am confused...

Comment: I am speaking about the gears reference to set the image, the getImage method that generates the random image path. In order for what I was working on to work there had to be a few things from the scope of rc.lua that  would need.  So I curried in the references and while I could use print to debug the internals of the call back, it still didn't work. See snippet. Ok so no code in comments. I edited my original to include another version of the method

Comment: As you can see from the addition code black at the bottom, I can curry in the references but it still doesn't function, even though print shows what it should

Comment: OK, I tried it with the gears timer and it works even without the closure variables for gears,getImage, screen. Very Cool, thanks that should be what I need. Awesome Thanks for all your help.

Comment: One last thing, if the desktop is refreshed, does it automatically kill the process, so when the desktop starts again the old loop is gone? thanks again for all your help.

Comment: There is no extra process. This runs inside of AwesomeWM. So yes, everything is cleaned up when AwesomeWM exits or restarts.

Comment: Ok thanks, at this point I still have to figure out where the memory leak is coming from as I posted in my final below, which is the actual configuration I ended up with. after 10 or so minutes it starts chewing up craploads of memory and has processes that will bury one of my CPU cores. Below is what I ended up with, if you have a minute, let me know if I am doing something supremely stupid.  Thanks again.

Comment: I would guess that the problem is https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/issues/2858. Lua's garbage collector does not clean up after setting a wallpaper. You could try adding a call to `collectgarbage("collect")` in your timer.

Comment: OK, I went the path of least resistance first and just added the call to the garbage collector in the timer CB without the "start and stop" called in the linked examples and it seemed to do the trick. I ran it in awmtt for an hour and it was fine, I used short-timers to speed up the possibility of a problem and it was good. Then I loaded it into my normal rc.lua and set the timers more reasonable. It has been running now for some time without incident. Thanks again for your help and extraordinary patience. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the finished implementation using the advice of @uli schlachter, I have found however that it seems to periodically suck up huge amounts of ram and CPU. If someones knows the reason it would be great, this is far easier than a bash or other implementation.

```
-- wallpaper changer routine
local lfs = require('lfs') -- lua file system
local dir = "/home/jerry/Documents/wallpaper" --images location
local images = {} -- images collection
local idx = 0 -- index for the image collection
math.randomseed(os.time())
-- function to generate the image count for the randomize function
local function tablelength(T)
    local count = 0
    for _ in pairs(T) do count = count + 1 end
    return count
end
-- function to read the images from the directory 
local function readImages(path)
    for file in lfs.dir(path) do
        if file ~= "." and file ~= ".." then
            images[idx] = path .. '/' .. file
            idx = idx + 1
        end
    end
end
-- execute read the images
readImages(dir);
-- grab the image count
imageCount = tablelength(images)
-- Generate the random image path
local function getImage()
    number = math.random(1, imageCount)
    return images[number]
end
-- call back for timer 
local function cb(screenIndex)
    return function()
        print(getImage())
        gears.wallpaper.maximized(getImage(), screen[screenIndex], true)
        return true;
    end
end
-- partial application of the
-- call back for the timer
-- pre-apply the screen index to create the
-- four separate cb's one for each screen
cb1 = cb(1)
cb2 = cb(2)
cb3 = cb(3)
cb4 = cb(4)
-- create the timers with unique time spans 
-- to sell the ramdomized approach 
local timer1 = gears.timer.start_new(14, cb1)
local timer2 = gears.timer.start_new(16, cb2)
local timer3 = gears.timer.start_new(18, cb3)
local timer4 = gears.timer.start_new(20, cb4)
-- trigger the timers 
timer1:emit_signal("timeout")
timer2:emit_signal("timeout")
timer3:emit_signal("timeout")
timer4:emit_signal("timeout")
```

Final version of the call back with the call to the garbage collector

```
-- call back for timer
local function cb(screenIndex)
    return function()
        gears.wallpaper.maximized(getImage(), screen[screenIndex], true)
        collectgarbage("step", 4000)
        return true;
    end
end
```

Comment: If you want random timeouts, well, you can just do so. `return false` in your callback to stop the timer and instead start a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The awesome library `gears` has a `timer`:

```lua
local gears = require("gears")
local naughty = require("naughty")

gears.timer {
    timeout   = 10,
    call_now  = true,
    autostart = true,
    callback  = function()
        naughty.notify({ title = "This runs every 10 seconds" })
    end
}
```

https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/gears.timer.html